# Fill all slices of jqplot pie chart in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

I am creating a `jQuery` mobile app using the mvc3. In this I have created the `jqPlot` pie chart.

It does not show colors for all slices of the pie chart,
i.e it sometimes show color for one slice even when there are four slices in the chart, and for the other three slices it shows white background instead of its defined slice background color.

I want it to show every time a full chart with solid color fill.

The image of `jqPlot` pie-chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH4o9.png

I am using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     var data = [
            ['Correct Answers', @Correct_Answer], ['Incorrect Answers', @Incorrect_Answer], ['Skipped Answers', @Skipped_Answer],
            ['Unseen Answers', @Unseen_Answer]
  ];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('score_chart', [data],
    {
        seriesColors: ["#83abc0", "#64d6f4", "#3399ff", "#03597a"],
        highlightColors: ["#ADC7D5", "#99E3F6", "#78BAFE", "#568FA6"],
        seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            fill: true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                padding: 5,
                fill: true,
                fillAndStroke: true,
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },

        legend: { show: true, location: legendlocation },

    });

});
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you please build a http://jsfiddle.net which would present your problem? This what u experience is v unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in this code. I did a sample from the code you have provided and it works fine. [See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/G6gQk/5/)

Are you sure you have all `JavaScript` and `CSS` files correctly imported?